# Unable to update android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm using `Android Studio 3.3.2`. When I try to update the version of Android Studio, it shows an error. It also mentions that there is no solution to the same error.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Try downloading the newest version manually from https://developer.android.com/studio

Answer (score 0):

Go to your android studio installation folder then search for this file. After this 
copy the file to a safe place then remove it from android studio folder, so try to update android studio again. If something goes wrong, the fastest way to solve this problem is by remove your old android studio version then download and  install the new Android Studio version from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio).